# Can i connect WSO2 identity server with external KDC?

Tags: wso2, mit-kerberos, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

In our project, Client has their own KDC server and client want our WSO2 should talk to client KDC for authentication. I know that how to enable kerberos in WSO2 but I am not able to established connection between our WSO2 to client KDC server(In short, i want to connect WSO2 identity server to external KDC server).

Answer (score 1):

We do not support this in the currently released versions of the WSO2 Identity Server. However, we have successfully done an implementation of authentication with an external KDC for Identity Server 5.3.0 release.

You might be able to test this with the next milestone release of Identity Server.